# silverlight putting item to listbox and view only some part of that object

Tags: silverlight

We are working on a project with my friends and we are stuck with some point i hope you could able to help us .The problem is we are getting object from a service that we wrote and we want to put objects to listbox but in interface we would like to see only few item of that object .to make situation more clear lets say we have object a includes {name surname id} we want to put this object to list box but we would like to see only name and surname in interface .Thanks in advance .

Can ELDEM

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at a Silverlight databinding example with a ListBox, such as this one: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-tutorial-part-5-using-the-listbox-and-databinding-to-display-list-data.aspx

Basically, you define the ListBox with the elements and styling you want and then use databinding for each of the properties you want to display: name, surname, id.

Answer (score 0):

With Silverlight 5 you also can use **Implicit DataTemplate** that allows templates to be automatically applied to databound items based on their types.